# Redirecting to a page based on the sub-domain

Tags: 8, redirection

How can I redirect visitors to a specific page based on the sub-domain? For example:

- www.site.com goes to frontpage
- checklist.site.com goes to checklist.site.com/checklist

My server is set to work with a wildcard (*.site.com). All sub-domains point to the same Drupal site.

I found [Redirect based on query string](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/237890/redirect-based-on-query-string) about redirecting in Drupal 8, but I am not able to achieve what I want following what reported there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked post points in the right directions, but contains a lot of code you don't need. Use this change record https://www.drupal.org/node/2013014 instead and check $request->getHost():

```
  public function checkForRedirection(RequestEvent $event) {
    if ($event->getRequest()->getHost() == '...') {
      $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse('http://example.com/foo/'));
    }
  }
```

For a non-coding solution you can try **Redirect Domain**, a submodule of [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect).